# Link AusPost API to display in form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to have a form, where the user types a suburb or postcode, I want to verify it using the AUSPOST API -https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/pac/explorer/postcode-search

I also want to autofill the suburb once I get response back from AUSPOST and then send data to Zapier.

Comment: What did you try, what are you expecting, what did you get?

Comment: I tried following this - however obviously it's php and not rails.. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated http://www.shahabqamar.com/computers-technology/up-and-running-with-the-auspost-postcode-api-using-php-and-jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. here we expect you to have a go at it yourself first, then come back to us when you get stuck on a particular bug. Generally speaking, we won't give you "pointers"... why don't you start with the PHP one open in one window and an empty ruby file in the other. Start by writing up what is happening in comments in your ruby file. Then do all the parts you know how to do (eg control flow statements or anything simple and obvious).

Comment: Then add pseudocode for all the parts you are unsure about... just have a guess at how you'd do it if you could make up the language yourself... then try googling for each of those parts to see if ruby really does that... anything you're 8still8 unsure about... then come back to us and ask about and we can help you figure out how to do.